# Que fontes de dados é possivel usar em Unity3d?

Tags: unity3d

Em todos os exemplos de armazenamento de dados em Unity3d que vi, utilizaram XML.

Em que outras fontes de dados é possivel armazenar ?

Comment: Sim.. tanto em DB como em windows registry, etc: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=unity+3d+database+tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IboxDB
nao usei, mais ta no forum do unity
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/iboxdb-lightweight-embedded-database.217097/